# MIDI Device not listed in /dev/tty*

Tags: python, macos, serial-port, midi

My MIDI keyboard is not showing up running

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

In fact, there is no entry containing "usb" or anything.
In Audio Midi Setup, the keyboard shows up and it works with my DAW.
Also, running

```
ioreg -p IOUSB -l
```

gives me plenty information on my keyboard, but no serial port (I guess, see bottom of post).

However I want to use it in combination with [py-midi](https://pypi.org/project/py-midi/), so I don't know what path to input in

```
conn = MidiConnector('/dev/serial0')
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

```
 | +-o USB Keystation 49e@14130000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000015e5, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (778 ms), retain 30>
| |   {
| |     "sessionID" = 7807069093660
| |     "iManufacturer" = 1
| |     "bNumConfigurations" = 1
| |     "idProduct" = 144
| |     "bcdDevice" = 275
| |     "Bus Power Available" = 250
| |     "USB Address" = 4
| |     "bMaxPacketSize0" = 64
| |     "iProduct" = 2
| |     "iSerialNumber" = 0
| |     "bDeviceClass" = 0
| |     "Built-In" = No
| |     "locationID" = 336789504
| |     "bDeviceSubClass" = 0
| |     "bcdUSB" = 256
| |     "USB Product Name" = "USB Keystation 49e"
| |     "PortNum" = 3
| |     "non-removable" = "no"
| |     "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
| |     "bDeviceProtocol" = 0
| |     "IOUserClientClass" = "IOUSBDeviceUserClientV2"
| |     "IOPowerManagement" = {"DevicePowerState"=0,"CurrentPowerState"=4,"CapabilityFlags"=32768,"MaxPowerState"=4,"DriverPowerState"=4}
| |     "kUSBCurrentConfiguration" = 1
| |     "Device Speed" = 1
| |     "USB Vendor Name" = "Evolution Electronics Ltd."
| |     "idVendor" = 2637
| |     "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
| |     "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBDevice"
| |   }
```

Comment: In general, MIDI devices use a different protocol and do not show up as serial ports. The py-midi library is not useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I used [pygame.midi](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html) which works fine.